# Generate a 1-5 number from a byte array

Tags: java, range, checksum, crc32

I have the need to consistently generate a number between 1-5 from a  byteArray input.

I was thinking to use a CRC32 checksum so I have a long number.

I would need to translate the long to something between 1-5.

Is it a good solution? How could I achieve this transformation in a consistent way in Java?

Thanks

Update:
to better understand my requirements:
I have a set of images on my website and I want these to be served by multiple subdomains to parallelize browser downloads. I'm going to have 5 subdomains serving the same images. I want one image to be requested only to one subdomain to use browser caching consistently. 
more here [Reduce site load time with multiple CDN sub-domains](http://cloudinary.com/blog/reduce_site_load_time_with_multiple_cdn_sub_domains)

Comment: if you downvote it would be helpful to understand why

Comment: What are your requirements? Why 1..5? (Not my downvote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a number that depends on the contents of the array, you can use:

```
int yourNumber = Arrays.hashCode(yourArray) % 5 + 1;
```